# Is there a name for magmas in which $y*(a*b) = (y*a)*(y*b)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote magmas, suppose $f$ is a homomorphism $X \rightarrow Y$, and let $y \in Y$ satisfy the following condition.

$$\forall a,b \in Y : y*(a*b) = (y*a)*(y*b)$$

Then $y * f$ is a homomorphism.

**Question.** Is there a name for magmas $Y$ in which every $y \in Y$ satisfies the aforementioned condition?

**Proof of claim.** The following are equal

1. $(y * f)(x*x')$
2. $y*f(x*x')$
3. $y*[f(x)*f(x')]$
4. $[y*f(x)]*[y*f(x')]$
5. $(y*f)(x) * (y*f)(x')$

**A couple of basic observations for interested parties.**

Let $Y$ denote a magma.

1. If $Y$ is [medial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma) and $y \in Y$ is idempotent, then $y$ has the property of interest. (Easy exercise).
2. Conversely, if $y \in Y$ satisfies the property of interest condition, then we may deduce that $y$ is idempotent, so long as there exists an idempotent $i \in Y$ that is also a right-identity of $y$. (*Proof.* Just put $a$ and $b$ equal to $i$).

Comment: tylerco816 seems to have answered your question, so I will just offer some food for thought. If you add in an extra condition that, for every $a,b\in Y$, $\exists!c\in Y$ such that $a*c=b$, then you would have a [Rack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles), or a Quandle if you further add that, for all $a\in Y$, $a*a=a$. My topology professor has done some work in knot theory with quandles, which I find is very interesting.

Comment: @BrianScholl, thanks! They look totally cool, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Ha! I just realized that my professor is even listed in the external links for the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @BrianScholl, what's his name?

Comment: [J. Scott Carter](http://www.southalabama.edu/mathstat/personal_pages/carter/). His article [A Survey of Quandle Ideas](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4429) is listed in the external links for the Racks and Quandles wikipedia page.

Comment: @BrianScholl, thanks that's a cool bit of trivia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently they are called (left) distributive magmas

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/lecture-notes-in-logic/Logic-Colloquium-90-ASL-Summer-Meeting-in-Helsinki/chapter/About-the-irreflexivity-hypothesis-for-free-left-distributive-magmas/lnl/1235423706)